# jquery dynamically adding a selector to existing function as watch object

Tags: jquery, selector

being new to jquery, I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically add a `selector` or indeed any object to a functions watch list (don't know the proper term yet) `$(selector).function()`

For example I have dynamically added a cancel button to a modal. The id of this button is random. is there a way to add it to the below `$('#closeX', '#mask', '#RANDOM_BUTTON_ID')` to perform the same actions as closeX & mask?

```
$('#closeX, #mask').on('click', function() {
  $('#modalBox').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $("#mask").css("display", "none");
      // code to remove dynamic button from parent
    });
   return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common class to add the event dynamically to multiple controls instead of id of controls. Assign common class to all control existing and dynamically addeed and use `on` for binding event dynmically added controls.

Use `$('.commonclass')` instead of `$('#closeX', #mask', '#RANDOM_BUTTON_ID')`

**HTML**

```
  <input type="button" id="closeX" class="commonclass" />
  <input type="#mask" id="closeX" class="commonclass" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.commonclass').on('click', function() {
  $('#modalBox').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $("#mask").css("display", "none");
      // code to remove dynamic button from parent
    });
   return false;
 });
```

Comment: thx @adil, I have added a dummy class to the dynamic elements and that works. I will see if there are any other suggestions if not will accept as answer. Art